# Is it possible to create a condition in HTML?

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body style = "background-color: green;">

<?php

$inicioFibonacciErro = $fimFibonacciErro = "";
$inicioFibonacci = $fimFibonacci = "";

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(empty($_POST["inicioFibonacci"])){
        $inicioFibonacciErro = "O primeiro numero da sequencia eh necessario";
    }
    else{
        $inicioFibonacci = test_input($_POST["inicioFibonacci"]);
    }
    if(empty($_POST["fimFibonacci"])){
        $fimFibonacciErro = "O ultimo numero da sequencia eh necessario";
    }
    else{
        $fimFibonacci = test_input($_POST["fimFibonacci"]);
    }
}

function test_input($dados){
    $dados = trim($dados);
    $dados = stripslashes($dados);
    $dados = htmlspecialchars($dados);
    return $dados;
}
?>

<h1 style = "text-align: center; color: red;">Digite os valores desejado pra a    sequencia de fibonacci</h1>
<!-- Caso queira mandar pra outra pagina utilizar action = "nomedapagina" -->
<!-- Caso queira mandar pra a propria pagina '<?php echo  htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>' -->
<form action= <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>  method="post"> 
Primeiro numero da sequencia: <input type="text" name="inicioFibonacci" />
<spam class = "error">* <?php echo $inicioFibonacciErro ?> </spam> <br /><br />
Ultimo numero da sequencia: <input type="text" name="fimFibonacci" />
<spam class = "error">* <?php echo $fimFibonacciErro ?> </spam> <br /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Veja o resultado!" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This code will generate a page that requires two numbers to create a fibonacci sequence. I have written a conditional that shows a message to the user if he didn't write one these two numbers.

My doubt here is: The action i'm using is useful to send the error (if there is some) to the same page. But if there isn't any erros nothing happens.

What I want do, if possible, is to create a condition where I use this action if there is an error, but if there is not, it use the action to send the numbers to other page that will show the fibonacci sequence.

Comment: For the love of Dog, please indent your code

Comment: The tag is span not spam :-)

Comment: it is indented, but I got a little confused when I copied it to this site. It was my first question here, so I left it all with 4 spaces to keep inside the block. Sorry. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can embed HTML in PHP conditionals during page generation as follows:

```
<p>Some html goes here</p>
<?php if(CONDITION) { ?>
  <p>Unlimited html goes here</p>
<?php } else { ?>
  <p>However much html you want to handle the false-case goes here</p>
<?php } ?>
```

If you want to perform conditionals *after* the page has been generated, you will need a client-side scripting language: JavaScript.

Comment: That's a nice trick. I knew how to add lots of `echo` in php; never thought you could simply "turn off" php for a minute and write plain html.

Comment: you can go into and out of PHP as often as you'd like in a script

Comment: @AndrewBrown - I knew that you could go in and out of php. I didn't realize that the code "would continue where it left off" right in the middle of a loop - and that the intervening html would either become part of the document, or not... I learn something new every day. This was today's new thing.

Comment: This was a very useful tip, Thanks. Now I have another problem, but I will try to fix it myself, based on your advice.

Comment: While you can turn PHP off and on as much as you'd, I would strongly advise against combining the mark-up and logic this way, except for very small projects that you'll never have to look at again, otherwise the code becomes unreadable fast. For smaller projects, you can prepare output beforehand and echo in the markup, e.g. in OP's case, you could just do `$error = '<span class="error">Some error</span>'` and `<?php echo $error ?>` on the page where appropriate, so if $error never gets filled, nothing happens; for larger projects, look into templating.

Answer (score 0):

you can use template frameworks (such as smarty) to use conditions to determine which html code to display. for example say you have results where one of the columns has a value of 1 or 2, you could take your result set and do this (html tags shown just to show the blending)

```
<table>
{foreach $results as $result}
    <tr><td>
    {if $result.mycol == 1}
        {$result.mycol}
    {else}
        random text
    {/if}
    </td></tr>
{/foreach}
</table>
```

this would output something like

```
1
random text
1
1
random text
```

in the case of smarty, your html code goes in a file with the extension .tpl and you use your php code to send the php variables to the template

```
$smarty->assign("results", $results);
$smarty->display("results.tpl");
```